# How to reference Enums using integers for use in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, oop, enums

I am trying to create a deck out of a card object. This card Object has two `enums`, an int and a `boolean` as shown below. In order to create this deck, I need to cycle through the suits and face values.

Unfortunately this would require 4*13 if statements to accomplish if I must reference each `enum` value by its name, i.e. `card[0] = new Card(Suit.Spade, Face.two, j, false);`

What I need to know is if there is a way to set each card their `enum` values by rather than Suit.Spade, something like suit.int so that the below would work without 52 if statements. The i simply counts cards, and the `Suit.j, Face.k` is just an example of what I am looking for.

```
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int k = 1;


    while(j <= suitCount)
    {
        k = 0;
        while(k <= faceCount)
        {
            card[i] = new Card(Suit.j, Face.k, i, false);

            k++;
            i++;
        }
        j++;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

try something like:

```
int i = 0;
List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>(Suit.values().length * Face.values().length);
for (Suit suit : Suit.values()){
    for (Face face : Face.values()){
        cards.add(new Card(suit, face, i, false));
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better than my answer. +1

Comment: `cards.add(new Card(suit, face, i++, false)` +1

Comment: @StephenP Yes, I know you can inline i++, but sometimes people prefer it on a separate line for readability. So I followed the style provided by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Use the implicit static `#values()` method.

```
Suit[] allSuits = Suit.values();
Face[] allFaces = Face.values();

// ...

card[i] = new Card(allSuits[j], allFaces[k], i, false);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: This is correct but you should retrieve values just once outside the loop and save them in a Suit[] and a Face[].

Comment: @JohnWatts that's what `// ...` is meant to imply.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
for (Suit s : Suit.values())
{
  for (Face f : Face.values())
  {
     card[i] = new Card(s, f, i, false);
     i++;
  }
}
```

maybe

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the same as puce's answer, but since I took the time to type it all up...

```
package com.example.cards;

public class Card
{
    private Suit suit;
    private Rank rank;

    public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank)
    {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public enum Suit {
        SPADE, HEART, CLUB, DIAMOND;
    }

    public enum Rank {
        ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN,
        EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING
    }

    /* Test building a deck of cards */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Card[] deck = new Card[52];
        int i = 0;

        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
                deck[i++] = new Card(suit, rank);
            }
        }
    }
}
```